# Why use throw in this scenario or others? | Swift

Tags: swift

Essentially while this is certainly a basic question with numerous reasons, I cannot seem to understand why it would be good idea to use throw when writing functions that validate.

For example if you take this simple username and password validation scenario, why would anyone want to use throw to help with the validation?

Does it just come down to coding style preference? Or is there a good reason one would opt for using throw for the return of this function?

```
enum ReturnMessages: String {
    case passed, failed, tooshort, nonumbers
}

func validateCredentials(username: String, password: String) -> ReturnMessages {
    guard (username.count >= 4 && password.count >= 4) else {return ReturnMessages.tooshort}
    guard (password.rangeOfCharacter(from: .decimalDigits) != nil) else {return ReturnMessages.nonumbers}
    
    return ReturnMessages.passed
}

validateCredentials(username: "jeff", password: "password")
```

Comment: IMHO, it would not be a good idea. Instead, even go ahead and enhance your `ReturnMessages` type, which should be an enum with associated values, for example: `enum ValidationResult { case valid, case errors([Error]) }`. Then enhance your validation function, which may take a list of "criteria" which define and check various distinct properties of your credential. Each failed check adds a corresponding error to the final validation result.

Comment: In other scenarios, throwing might be an option when unexpected runtime errors occur.

Answer (score 1):

Returning an enum value in this case is fine because the possibility to fail is quite high.

But consider that you have to use always a `switch` to distinguish the *good* from the *bad* path.

On the other hand in many cases the expected result is `passed` or some return value with a very low rate of errors. So isn’t it a better idea to return the good path directly and `throw` the bad paths.

The benefit is that you can continue your workflow without a runtime check good/bad.